# Getting error when running node -v

Tags: software-installation, node.js, terminal

I have been trying to install node.js for the last one hour. After reinstalling and removing nodejs numerous times, every time I run `node -v` I get the following error:

```
node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by node)
```

I have searched the internet for the solution, but they say that I have to do a clean reinstall of raspbian. 
 I don't want to have to do that, since I have quite a lot of stuff running. (Apache, SMB server, among other things). 
 I have been using nodesource as well as the offical download from nodejs.org. Thanks!